Cluster Standard Errors for glmmTMB object
I try to get clustered standard errors for my glmmTMB regression model:
Model <- glmmTMB(X ~ Y
               + A
               + B
               + C
               + (1|id)
               , ziformula = ~  A + B, family = nbinom2, data = data)

# Calculate cluster-robust standard errors
robust_vcov <- vcovCR(Model, cluster = data$fid, type = "CR0")

However I receive:
Error in nobs0(x) * vcov0(x, ...) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

